# weird typing error with private iterator in generic class

Tags: java, generics, types, iterator, java-7

I'm implementing a linked list in Java 1.7 and I don't understand this behaviour. The parts of the code that matter are this:

```
public class LListSent<T> implements Iterable<T>{
  //...
  public T get(int pos) {
      //...
  }
  //...
  private class LListSentIterator {
      private final LListSent list;
      private int currPos;
      private LListSentIterator(LListSent list) {
          this.list = list;
          currPos = 0;
      }
      //...
      @Override
      public T next() {
          return list.get(currPos++); //exception in this line
      }
  }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
incompatible Type: Object cannot be converted to T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class LListSent
```

eve though left.get return a `T` object. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list` variable is of type `LListSent` which is the raw type (so not parametrized) as such the get method called on this instance will return `Object` and not `T`.

Change the type of your variable to `LListSent<T>`.

Note that this will work because `LListSentIterator` is an inner class and has access to the type variable `T`.

A cleaner solution would be to parametrized your `LListSentIterator` class with a type parameter `S` and so your `list` variable would become of type : `LListSent<S>`

Comment: parametrizing LListSentIterator would only be necessary if it were a static class IMO.

Comment: @0x539 Either replace "LListSent.LListSentIterator#list" with ``LListSent.this`` or make "LListSent.LListSentIterator" declared as ``private static class`` with a generic-constrained ``LListSent`` field (which requires the class to be constrained, too).

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman that's true, I had forgotten that you could use `LListSent.this`. That's better, of course.